# How To Set Time Properly With Transient API WordPress

Tags: wordpress, api, cookies, transient

I have searched and cannot locate an answer to this already.

There is code in a website we are working with, that sets a cookie when the user logs into WordPress. Currently the cookie is being added, but the date (30 Days from today) for the cookie to expire is not being set properly. The cookie is present once login happens, but the date is not defined in the cookie for 30 days as intended.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'bro_set_universal_cookie' );
function bro_set_universal_cookie() {

global $i2sdk;
$email = wp_get_current_user()->user_email;

// get infusionsoft ID
$returnFields = array('Id');    
$client_data = $i2sdk->isdk->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);    
$Infusionsoft_ID = $client_data[0]['Id'];

setcookie( 'CookieName', $Infusionsoft_ID,  30 * DAYS_IN_SECONDS, '/', 
'.websitenamehere.com');

}

add_action('wp_head','rup_check_referrer');
function rup_check_referrer() {
if(get_post_type() == "sfwd-courses"){
     if(isset($_GET['registersuccess']) && $_GET['registersuccess']==1) 
{
         $cur_url=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
         header("Refresh:0; url=$cur_url");
     }
}
}
```

After looking into this, it appears that the section that has the Transients API date in it, this section:

```
30 * DAYS_IN_SECONDS
```

Is suppose to be:

```
30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS
```

As outlined here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

However, when changing that and removing the S from DAYS, the cookie is no longer applied at all. It is very strange.

If anyone can help to get the cookie expiration date to expire in 30 days, it would be greatly appreciated. Any examples of the proper code would be extremely helpful. I am assuming it has to do with this portion of the coding needing to be changed:

```
30 * DAYS_IN_SECONDS
```

Just not sure the best way to do so. Was thinking that not using the transients API for the date, but instead just writing the date to the cookie with php might be a better option? Something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'bro_set_universal_cookie' );
function bro_set_universal_cookie() {

global $i2sdk;
$email = wp_get_current_user()->user_email;

// get infusionsoft ID
$returnFields = array('Id');    
$client_data = $i2sdk->isdk->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);    
$Infusionsoft_ID = $client_data[0]['Id'];

setcookie( 'CookieName', $Infusionsoft_ID,  echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 
days")), '/', '.websitenamehere.com');

}

add_action('wp_head','rup_check_referrer');
function rup_check_referrer() {
if(get_post_type() == "sfwd-courses"){
     if(isset($_GET['registersuccess']) && $_GET['registersuccess']==1) 
{
         $cur_url=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
         header("Refresh:0; url=$cur_url");
     }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Seems like using this: `time() + (86400 * 30)`  for the time might be a good way to go as outlined here [link]https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp Still digging for the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed this one... the edit for the fix that I used was I changed this:

```
setcookie( 'CookieName', $Infusionsoft_ID,  30 * DAYS_IN_SECONDS, '/', '.websitenamehere.com');
```

To this new line of code I wrote after doing a bit of research. I realized whomever did the original code should not have used the transient API date replacement and just good 'ol PHP date was the answer:

```
setcookie( 'CookieName', $Infusionsoft_ID,  time() + (86400 * 30), '/', '.websitenamehere.com');
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future that may need it!